# std::sort on an std::vector compares but never replaces

Tags: c++

the array stays the same after the sort. How is that possible? I can see the healthy comparison result.

There's a model class that owns a std::vector:

```
private:
     std::vector<Contact> contacts;
```

The class contact has:

1. QString private member
2. QString private member getter - GetName()
3. Copy constructor that handles the members
4. Assignment operator that handles the members
5. < operator defined as follows:

---

```
bool Contact::operator < (const Contact& contact) const {
    QString str1 = contact.GetName();
    QString str2 = this->GetName();
    bool b = (QString::compare(str1,str2) < 0);
    return b;
}
```

I am debugging this method during sort, and i find that the correct "b" is returned, every time. The names are retrieved correctly, are compared correctly, and the "b" return code is always correct.

In the class that owns the vector, I have a sort method...

```
void ContactsModel::sort ()
{
    qDebug("Before Sorting: size: %d", this->contacts.size());

    for (int i=0; i< this->contacts.size(); i++)
    {
    QString str = contacts[i].GetName();
    qDebug(str.toAscii());
    }

    // trying to sort...
    std::sort(this->contacts.begin(), this->contacts.end());

    // PROBLEM: Output here is identical to what I had before the sort. The vector is not sorted, not even close. It's 52 random names in the same order they were initially put in the vector.

    qDebug("After Sorting: size: %d", this->contacts.size());
    for (int i=0; i< this->contacts.size(); i++)
    {
    QString str = contacts[i].GetName();
    qDebug(str.toAscii());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your sorting code.

Comment: Maybe because its already sorted? :)  Who knows without seeing an example of the problem.

Comment: -1 for not posting the code, and asking the question as if we've sixth sense, when OP doesn't use even common sense!

Comment: @Ron: Obviously the std::sort should change the vector. So the question really becomes "What am I doing incorrectly", and to answer that we will need to see what you are doing. Thus some code would be appreciated.

Comment: OK- I'll stop here. I'll tear up my code, put it back again, and if it still doesn't work - I'll post full source codes. I am sorry for bugging you without code.

Comment: The sorting is done by the same class that owns the std::vector. So no "by value" to the sort.

Comment: By the way, you can save typing by removing all instances of `this->`, which is not necessary in C++.  If you have name conflicts between parameters and members, rename one of them (examples include a 'm_' prefix or a '_' suffix).

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. But the fact that you use `contacts[]` half the time and `this->contacts[]` the other half make me suspicious there could be some name conflicts in the original code that you have edited out. Though I am curious why you copy the name out with `GetName()` rather than return a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

My assignment operator on the class stored in the vector was faulty.

My assignment operator wasn't returning a healthy "*this", instead it declared a new object, initialized it with the rhs data and returned it.

so the effect was as I described. Correct comparison, but no "swapping" due to this error.

Answer (score 1):

The vector is already sorted!!

Comment: What? `std::vector` is already sorted?

Comment: unfortunately, no. it's not sorted.. I wish that was the problem

Comment: @Nawaz: By the use of exclamation mark (bang) I assuming @Victor is being ironic.

Comment: @Martin: In that case, I would give him +1 :D

Answer (score 0):

Just to start with:

1. Your comparison functor (or operator<, or less) could be incorrect.
2. You could pass incorrect pair of iterators (v.begin, v.begin()).
3. It could be already sorted.

Comment: I am checking the comparison. It's healthy. I am passing v.begin(), v.end() to the sort method. My vector is definitely not sorted. this is why it's so baffling.

Answer (score 0):

> the *array* stays the same after the sort.

What array? Are you initializing a vector from an array? In that case, the vector has its own copy of the data, and sorting the vector will have no influence on the array. Example:

```
int array[] = {5, 2, 7, 3};
std::vector<int> vec(array + 0, array + 4);
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Now the vector will contain the numbers `{2, 3, 5, 7}`, but the array will remain unchanged. If you want to sort the array itself, just do so:

```
int array[] = {5, 2, 7, 3};
std::sort(array + 0, array + 4);
```

Comment: The vector is initialized by pushing 50 names into it. Then the same class that did the pushing, calls std::sort. I should have said the VECTOR stays the same. Forget about an array.